# Error converting SQL Server DATETIME... How do I keep the date the same?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following data in my stored procedure:

[image]

I query parse and save the data like this...

```
private StringBuilder GetDataFromStoredProc(string connectionString, string storedProcName)
{
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        try
        {
            using (var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(storedProcName, sqlCon))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 300; // five minutes default

                    sqlCon.Open();

                    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        //Get All column 
                        var columnNames = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount)
                                                .Select(reader.GetName)
                                                .ToList();

                        // Create headers
                        sb.Append(string.Join("|", columnNames));

                        // Append Line
                        sb.AppendLine();

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                            {
                                string value = reader[i].ToString();
                                sb.Append(value.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ") + "|");
                            }

                            sb.Length--; // Remove the last comma
                            sb.AppendLine();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return sb;
}
```

... somehow the values in the `Plan_Start_Date` column show up as `MM/DD/YYYY` format...

On the right is the result of the above code against the database, on the left is the result of the current process which solves this problem using an SSIS package...

Is there some special converter or flag i need to use so that my dates aren't converted in this manner?

Comment: You've only tagged [tag:t-sql] here, however, the only code you show is C#; what are you actually asing about here?

Comment: What is the actual data type of the column in the schema? Is it a `datetime`? If so you should be able to both read from it and write to it using c# ado.net and the .net type `DateTime`. You should never be converting to/from a string with the exception of displaying something in the UI (presentation layer) for the end user. See also [`SqlDataReader.GetDateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlDataReader_GetDateTime_System_Int32_)

Comment: That's what `reader.ToString()` does. Pass a format string.

Comment: [For the 1024 time – DateTime has no format!](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/for-the-1024-time-datetime-has-no-format/)

Comment: When reading from a database you should not use `string value = reader[i].ToString();`, get the object either as `object` if you are using abstraction or as the native type. If this is too much code for you then I agree and so do others, that is why ORMs were invented. Check out Entity Framework or Dapper (in no particular order). These provide a configurable layer between your c# code and the data store.

Comment: exactly... so how can I get my dates to properly display as they are in SQL Server?

Comment: As a side note never rethrow exceptions using `throw ex;`, just write `throw;`. Doing this will preserve the stack trace of the exception whereas `throw ex;` resets the stack trace to the point where you are trying to rethrow.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it...

Evaluate the column's datatype and the rest is history...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check regional setting of your computer and its date and time format .

When you read a datetime field, Its presentation format obey regional setting of your computer. Your computer means the client you are programming and the server, host your web application.